# Saving partitioned Parquet

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I want to save the df as partitioned parquet, as record by record insertion is taking time. can any one help how can I save it and point to a hive table.

Comment: Actualy I keep getting the data incrementaly, I am going with dynamic partition, rather inserting the data I want to save that directly, as parquet partitioned by one columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.write.parquet("/parquet/file/path")
```

Then you can create a `Hive external table` pointing to the parquet file location.

Comment: Actually It keeps getting the data incrementally, I am going with dynamic partition, rather inserting the data I want to save that directly, as parquet partitioned by one columns.

Comment: @HEMANTHKUMAR: What do you mean by parquet partitioned by one column? you mean Hive table partitioning?

Comment: Yeah, I have partitioned the hive table

Comment: Currently I am inserting the record record in hive which is stores as parquet, but I want save the df directly as partitioned parquet rather inserting record by record.

Comment: @HEMANTHKUMAR: The above code does the same what you are expecting.. it will not insert the records in Hive. It will store the DF as parquet files (Partitioned)

Comment: so Can't I access the same data in hive terminal,if i save like that

Comment: @HEMANTHKUMAR: You can create Hive External table on top of this parquet file path, then you can access through Hive QL Terminal.

Comment: Also, I have df created in sqlContext, I am unable to access in hiveContext, could you please me out in that as well